# LinkedIn Android SDK confused with consumer key and consumer secret?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

LinkedIn recently launched an official Android SDK which facilitates LinkedIn integration.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

but the documentation not explaining much for setting previously acquired consumer key and consumer secret which getting while app registration process.any one working around it?

Comment: I was wrong with my answer since its about HTTP settion Access token. Maybe they gonna utilize theese keys later? However if you look at http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/ this lib uses these keys in oauth_cosumer.properties file.

Comment: Anyway, appreciating your effort.Thank you. :)

Comment: Yeah anoop i have worked with it, seems easy way around than Rest API :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of defining your package and hash name within your LinkedIn application configuration, as described in the Getting Started documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk#application) is all that is required for LinkedIn to map your mobile application to your particular LinkedIn application.

If you've done that correctly, there's no need to worry about your consumer key and secret values.

Comment: That's nice.thanks #Justin for your quick feedback :)